# Disable Google Calendar Autoscrolling in week view

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, windows-7, google-calendar-api

(Story: My Google Calendar in Chrome automatically scrolls to random times on load. I think it is designed to jump to the current time, but for my two calendars this is never the case, also not from another computer using Firefox. The auto-scrolling is dependant on the window height and when I jump to next/previous weeks, it always scrolls to the very bottom.)

What I want to achieve is that Google Calendar will not automatically scroll down in week view, preferably with **Tampermonkey** or similar JS injecting addons.

Currently I am using a script that I have written to simply jump back to the top afterwards.

```
...
// @match        https://calendar.google.com/calendar*
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

$("#scrolltimedeventswk").scrollTop(0);

var url = window.location.href

setTimeout(report, 10)

function report() {
    var tmp = window.location.href
    if(tmp != url)
    {
        if($("#scrolltimedeventswk").scrollTop() != 0)
        {
            $("#scrolltimedeventswk").scrollTop(0);
            url = tmp;
        }
    }
    setTimeout(report, 10);
}
```

It works just fine but is really dirty. I want to get to the root of the problem instead of fixing the impacts of the problem. So my question is, where would I start to debug to look for that integrated auto-scrolling function and disable it?

Comment: You may check back to this Google [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/calendar/O2fpZq36otA/OJ1Lj3rhCgAJ). I suggest if your script work just fine, keep it as is. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately the method used in that forum is something quite different as the problem is solved by intercepting user interaction, whereas my problem doesn't involve user interaction. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: I'm with you, this is super annoying!